# Google Calendar API - use Javascript to insert events in ANOTHER user's calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Trying to make a web app where others can view my availability and schedule an apt with me...so it will be them on their computer on my site.  I can do the Oath just fine for me...but when someone else visits the site, it is just for their calendar.  I can't seem to find anything on how to make it show my calendar.  I've gone up and down the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) page but can't seem to figure out how to make the user fixed on the api calls.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want others to view your calendar, you can make your calendar public or share your calendar with the users. Other than these two I cannot think of any other options. When sharing your calendar, be cautious that users cannot have access to delete the existing events. You can also check this https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en Let me know if your use case is different.

Comment: Requests have to be authenticated as a user authorized to edit the specific calendar. They approach most people take is have your credentials protected on a server and when users have an event to be added those requests get proxied through the server where the authentication gets added.

Comment: @SGC, thanks but I do know about that.  I would like a web-app for users to view my calendar (that's the part you mention) but I would like a form for them to reserve a time with me so that when they submit the form, it inserts the new event into my calendar automatically.

Comment: @abraham, looks like I may have to go that route which would stink. Was hoping to have it run right on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service account, share your calendar read-write with this service account and then have this service account always be the authenticated user (instead of using Oauth). More on service accounts: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: That looks like it!  Looks like php and curl here I come!  Thanks for this.